# DOMXPath does not print HTML-source in <pre><code>...</code></pre> on screen

Tags: php, domxpath

I created a little script that modifies the output of a specific page:

```
foreach ( $markers as $marker ) {
    foreach ( $xpath->query( '//text()[not(ancestor::a) and not(ancestor::pre) and not(ancestor::code) and not(ancestor::img) and not(ancestor::script) and not(ancestor::style)]' ) as $node ) {
        $text     = $marker[ 'text' ];
        $url      = $marker[ 'url' ];
        $tip      = strip_tags( $marker[ 'excerpt' ] );
        $tooltip  = ( $tooltip ? "data-uk-tooltip='' title='$tip'" : "" );
        $replaced = preg_replace(
            '/\b' . preg_quote( $text, "/" ) . '\b/i',
            "<a href='$url' $hrefclass target='$target' $tooltip>\$0</a>",
            $node->wholeText
        );
        $newNode  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
        $newNode->appendXML( $replaced );
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild( $newNode, $node );
    }
}

$event->setContent( utf8_encode( $dom->saveHTML()) );
```

Now I got a problem:

If the page-content contains a `<pre><code><strong>some-content</strong></code></pre>`  the elements are not displayed as text - they are getting parsed as source code.

So it does not display the text `<strong>some-content</strong>` but parses it and displays **some-content**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your XML output in a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

```html
<textarea style="width:100%; height:150px">
<strong>
some-content
</strong>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, because my script edits the view of an CMS. If a webmaster is using an highlighting-plugin for this CMS, that makes use of `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` the output should not be wrapped to an inbox.